# Enable twilio phone number to send sms

Tags: twilio

My Twilio number is not enabled to send sms. How can I enable my twilio number to send sms?
It is showing "Messaging is unavailable for this phone number."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue with the "*first one's on us*" number.

Turns out, messaging capability depends on the type and country of the number.

I was automatically assigned a local number for my country, which did not allow messaging. If, however, you choose a custom number and go for one in the US, you are given SMS capability (at least I was just now).

If you already have your **one free number** assigned, you can release it and choose a new number for free.

Answer (score 1):

Not every twilio number is capable of sending / receiving SMSs. Take a look into https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/can-i-send-or-receive-text-messages-with-a-twilio-toll-free-phone-number

Also, if you follow the link they provide there, you can read the following

**Mobile numbers**

In most countries, mobile numbers are assigned to a particular range within the country’s telephone numbering plan so they can be easily distinguished from local numbers.  They are often the only type of number in the given country that can be used for sending and receiving messages.

Note that currently all mobile numbers Twilio provides are only SMS-enabled. You can not make or receive voice calls using these numbers.